# Tensorflow graph mode: effective reshaping of tensors in a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a list of tensors coming from a function. Atm the code look like this:

```
        @tf.function(reduce_retracing=REDUCE_RETRACING, jit_compile=JIT_COMPILE)            
        def _compute_jacobian(f, model, X, n_residuals, use_pfor):
            """compute the jacobian matrix and the hessian"""
            residuals = tf.reshape(f(X, model), (-1, 1))                                    
            jacs = jacobian(
                residuals,
                model.trainable_weights,                                                    
                use_pfor=use_pfor
            )   

            # jacs is a list of tensors
            #jacobians = [tf.reshape(j, (n_residuals, -1)) for j in jacs]                   
            jacobians = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [n_residuals, -1]), jacs)         
            
            J = tf.concat(jacobians, axis=1)                                                
            return J, residuals
```

There is two lines beginning with jacobians =. The first one works but I am afraid that list comprehension is a python mecanism that is hard to translate to Tensorflow operations and is taking time to compute. I read about an alternative involving tf.map_fn (second line of code). That might be better, but the tensors coming from jacs doesnt have the same rank. Hence the error: ValueError: Tried to convert 'tensor' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2.

Is there a Tensorflow efficient way to turn the shape of Tensors in a list to (n, -1) but with different ranks? I am using Tensorflow 2.13.*.